# Запятые в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что одна запятая лишняя. Может кто-нибудь грамотно объяснить?

"Издатели и редакция предупреждают, что информация в журнале не может быть использована как нормативная(,) и должна быть тщательно проверена перед ее использованием.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед "и" действительно не нужна, так как одиночный союз "и" соединяет в этом предложении два однородных сказуемых: "Информация... не может быть использована... и должна быть проверена".

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая не нужна. Однородные придаточные, соединённые неповторяющимся союзом И.

Одно придаточное, одно!!! И на Колю Остен-Бакена бывает проруха.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. 
Одиночный союз "и" соединяет в этом предложении два однородных сказуемых.